# How can I filter on column in a search result webpart?

Tags: search

SP2013 standard licence. I am using the search result webpart. Can I filter on some column value? I already filtering on contenttype like this:

```
 Path:{SiteCollection.URL}  ContentType:NieuwsDetailPagina {searchboxquery}
```

I would like to add extra filter like `columnx:TRUE`. `Columnx` is a boolean column on Contenttype "NieuwsDetailPagina".

Comment: Have you looked into RefinableString? It allows you to map to any site columns, then you can use it within search filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the column in the Crawled Properties of the Search Schema settings. Usually it will be named ows_Columnx (based on your example above. In order to Query that column create a new Managed Property mapping the crawled property to your new Managed Property.

Perform a full crawl and the you can search for your field by using the ManagedPropertyName=1 for Boolean field types.

Comment: Can I use it in the search query like this?: Path:{SiteCollection.URL} ManagedPropertyName=1  ContentType:NieuwsDetailPagina {searchboxquery}

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it.